# tfs2010 local build

Tags: build-process

I am currently playing with tfs2010 and realized that the build scripts are in fact workflows.

Does anybody know how to run a local build? In 2008 it was simple but 2010 seems tricky not to mention the complexity introduced by the workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a little about this particular scenario in this MSDN Forums post:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsprerelease/thread/08cb37be-dab6-4d76-b920-fa0183a2a18f

Basically, here's the response I gave to the person asking about the Desktop Build scenario:

> As far as the local build scenario,
>   there is not technically a way to run
>   the Workflow-based builds locally
>   (like the former Desktop Build
>   scenario.)  However, end users can
>   queue private builds using shelvesets
>   to go through the normal build process
>   to validate their work.  It uses your
>   existing build infrastructure but will
>   not perform parts of the default build
>   process since it's a "private" build. 
>   That may be a good alternative that
>   you could take advantage of!

Comment: :) sure, it is Microsoft, anything but agile. I can't conceive to not be able to run builds locally. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yep, you are right.  It appears they have taken down the Pre-Release forums and this was for TFS 2010 Beta.  I'll see if I can find the old forum post.